# Is there exist an $n \times n$ self adjoint matrix but non -diagonal matrix $\in$ $M_n( \mathbb{C})$?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Is  there exist   an  $n \times n$ self adjoint matrix   but non -diagonal matrix $\in$  $M_n( \mathbb{C})$?

My attempt : No , i think this  type of matrix doesnot exist  because  $A = X B X^{-1}$, where $B$ is a real diagonal matrix, then $B$ is self-adjoint

Is its true ?

Comment: What about real symmetric matrices which are non-diagonal?  In particular what about $\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @WETutorialSchool ya  this example  didn't  came in my mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self-adjoint matrices that are not diagonal are very common.  For $M_2(\mathbb{C})$ they often take the form $$\begin{bmatrix}a + b & c + i \,d \\ c - i \, d & a - b \end{bmatrix},$$
with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$.